# Including paypal-rest-sdk in react-native project produces an error

Tags: react-native, paypal-rest-sdk

When I import Paypal-Rest-SDK and try running:

```
react-native run-android
```

An error occurs:

```
"undefined is not a function(evaluating 'r(d[9]).configure')"
```

Before this error occurred, I deleted the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled all modules again, because I had a similar error with "evaluating process.versions.openssl". when I call `node -p process.versions`, the following is printed:

```
{ http_parser: '2.8.0',
  node: '8.12.0',
  v8: '6.2.414.66',
  uv: '1.19.2',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.32.0',
  napi: '3',
  openssl: '1.0.2p',
  icu: '60.1',
  unicode: '10.0',
  cldr: '32.0',
  tz: '2017c' }
```

and my Code is the following for using the paypal-sdk:

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Linking}           from 'react-native';

var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

paypal.configure({
  mode: 'sandbox', // Sandbox or live
  client_id: 'x',
  client_secret: 'y'});

export default class Paypal extends Component{
        constructor(props)
       {
            super(props);
            console.log(process);
       }
        render()
        {
            return(
                    <View>
                        <Text>This is gonna be a PayPal Thing</Text>
                    </View>
                   );
        }
 }
```

I hope someone can help me. I've googled almost the entire day for this issue.

**UPDATE** :
The Problem is not the include of the paypal-rest-sdk, but the next line when I try to configure the paypal variable. The error dissapears when I comment them out ...but as far as I know it is necessary to configure that

**Update No.2** 
After running 
    npm install --save paypal-rest-sdk
I'm back at the problem

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.versions.openssl')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `paypal-rest-sdk` which is NodeJS PayPal SDK, I belive it is not compatible with React Native. I suggest to try something React Native specific like

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-wrapper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal

Or use plain PayPal rest API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#api-requests

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know that. I'm gonna try using the plain PayPal Rest API which leaves more room for my own ideas.